# Android mounting RO /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 failed: Input/output error

Tags: android, sd-card, mount

Have in statusbar message "Damaged SD card". Vold or something is blocking write/read /dev/block/mmcbk1p1 device. How can i disable android OS (mb it's only a script) checking sdcard to mount read only microSD, which i can mount on another devices with no problems, as well on this device in recovery. Maybe as a solution can be replacing vold with old one to disable MTP modes and other useless things for me. Any Help?

```
shell@android:/dev/block # ls
mmcblk0
mmcblk0p1
...
mmcblk0p19
...
mmcblk1
mmcblk1p1
shell@android:/dev/block # busybox mount -t vfat -o rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noex
ec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,shortname=m
ixed /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/sdcard/sdcard2
,allow_utime=0020,shortname=mixed /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/sdcard/sdcard2    <
mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 on /mnt/sdcard/sdcard2 failed: Input/output
 error
255|shell@android:/dev/block #
```